# Is "things" natural?

Tags: idiomatic-language

X: We have barely talked since the divorce.

Y: Things are still complicated?

X: Yes.

Is Y's question natural (in particular "things") here?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this a perfectly natural way to refer to a situation in general.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's used constantly as a generic substitute. Like "How are things?" "I have things to do." "How did the match go? That thing went downhill quickly."